# How to extract files from pgp file

Tags: decrypt, pgp

I have a `a.zip.pgp` file along with an key.asc file. How can I extract the files from `a.zip.pgp` ?

I have tried the following:-

```
$ gpg --import key.asc
```

then

```
$ gpg --decrypt-files a.zip.pgp
gpg: encrypted with 2048-bit ELG-E key, ID 20242EB8, created 2009-12-17
gpg: encrypted with RSA key, ID 744D6CB7
gpg: decryption failed: secret key not available

$ gpk -k

pub   1024D/F8802D87 2009-12-17

uid                  Nsit-Poison <nsit_poison@yahoo.co.in>
sub   2048g/20242EB8 2009-12-17
```

Does anybody have any idea if this is because that I don't have the good key file ?

Comment: A pure guess is that the 'key.asc' file contains a *public key*, which can encrypt a file, which then can be decrypted with the correct *private key* (which you possibly don't have). This is the purpose of (p)gp(g). It would help to know the context in which you obtained these files.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have the wrong key.

`gpg -k` lists the public keys (ie, the keys you need to encrypt something).
You need the **private** key that matches the public key this file was encrypted with.
When you have it, `gpg -K` (note capital) will list it with `sec` ("secret") instead of `pub` in the output you excerpted above.